# I have dataset i need to convert into time series data but when i am passing the date it gives me error of ValueError: year is out of range?

Tags: python, pandas

I am very new python and ml please give me solution.

```
query = "Select created_date,device_data From smeonix.uplink_data"
result = session.execute(query, timeout=None)
row = result._current_rows 


uplink_data = pd.Series(row['device_data'].values,
                 index = pd.DatetimeIndex(data = 
                                          (tuple(pd.date_range('31/12/2018 00:00:00',
                                                                periods = 81389,
                                                                freq = 'A-DEC'))),
                                          freq = 'A-DEC'))
```

Comment: put some sample data for what you want as output. You have given high period value which makes no sense of generating that number of years.Put periods as 8 or 10 something then you will get the where you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

this is how we can print the date range by using the panda Dataframe:

```
 import pandas as pd
    from datetime import datetime
    import numpy as np
    date_rng = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', end='1/08/2018', freq='H')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html); your arguments to `date_range` are wrong.